# Microsoft Word Macro Running but NOT Executing Command

Tags: vba, ms-word, dependencies

I am attempting to write visual basic for the attached word document form to have dependent entry conditions that will mean when supplier A is selected in table 1, the form will only show the supplier A table, when supplier B is selection in table 1 the form will show the supplier B table and when supplier C is selected from table 1 the form will show the supplier C table.

When running the macro on visual basic, no errors are shown but when excuting the macro on the word document nothing happens.

The code I have is:

```
Sub ShowSupplierTable(ByVal supplier As String)
  Select Case supplier
    Case "Supplier A"
      SupplierATable.Visible = True
      SupplierBTable.Visible = False
      SupplierCTable.Visible = False
    Case "Supplier B"
      SupplierATable.Visible = False
      SupplierBTable.Visible = True
      SupplierCTable.Visible = False
    Case "Supplier C"
      SupplierATable.Visible = False
      SupplierBTable.Visible = False
      SupplierCTable.Visible = True
    Case Else
      MsgBox "Invalid supplier"
  End Select
End Sub

Private Sub SupplierASelected(ByVal sender As Object,       ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles SupplierA.SelectedIndexChanged
  ShowSupplierTable (SupplierA.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub SupplierBSelected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles SupplierB.SelectedIndexChanged
  ShowSupplierTable (SupplierB.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub SupplierCSelected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles SupplierC.SelectedIndexChanged
  ShowSupplierTable (SupplierC.Text)
End Sub

Sub SuppilerSelection()

End Sub
```

I am looking to create dependent drop down filliable word document but the macro will not run.

Comment: Just reformatted the code in your Question and notice that you have  SuppilerSelection instead of SupplierSelection, but no time to check if that typo might be a problem.

Comment: `Handles` is, as far as I know, not a VBA keyword but VB.Net